# Flipping of an image seems use lazy evaluation

Tags: image, racket, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to flip a list of images using rackets "2htdp/image".

Here is a minimal example of what doesn't work:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image)
(define images 
  (list
     (bitmap "../data/player/player1.png")
     (bitmap "../data/player/player2.png")
     (bitmap "../data/player/player3.png")))
(define flipped (map flip-horizontal images))
```

It seems to me (due to the speed the images get drawn in DrRacket) that the contents of the list "flipped" are evaluated lazily. Meaning only once I try to access the image its flipped version is calculated. This becomes a problem once I import this racket file into a universe (using "2htdp/universe") as I get poor performance initially when using the flipped images.

I looked at the [implementation](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/25cf0ea6102725375a503691fd763ac7a09d043f/pkgs/htdp-pkgs/htdp-lib/2htdp/private/image-more.rkt) of "flip-horizontal" and I can't see any obvious reasons for this. I didn't yet look into the implementation of "make-translate" and "make-image" though.

I was unable to force the evaluation of the images using force and the debugger shows object:image as the lists content. I am unsure as to what exactly happens and how to prevent the issue and actually calculate all images at start-up.

Any ideas why this happens and/or how to properly fix it? Thanks.

The approved answer is the solution to my problem, so I ended up just changing the last line to:

```
(define flipped (map (compose freeze flip-horizontal) images))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the image content isn't actually computed until it's time to display it. You can use [`freeze`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._freeze%29%29), which converts the image into a bitmap, if you need to compute it ahead of time.

In your example, try changing the definition of `flipped` to the following:

```
(define flipped (map (compose1 freeze flip-horizontal) images))
```